# C - How to insert an integer value into an array

Tags: c

I have a problem with this code:

main :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Function.h"
int main()
{

int B[9]; 

saisie_B_M(&B[9]);

return 0;

}
```

Function.c

```
void saisie_B_M(int B[9])
{

int i;

for(i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    printf("Une cellule morte ayant %d voisins sera t-elle morte ou vivante à la génération suivante ? \n", i);
    scanf("%d", &B[i]);
        }
    }
```

function.h

```
#ifndef Function_H_INCLUDED
#define Function_H_INCLUDED
void saisie_B_M(int B[9]);
#endif // Function_H_INCLUDED
```

The principle is simple, it is an array of 9 and I just return a value in each cell of the table. But there is a bug at the end and I don't know why the compiler does not show a message.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You're passing in to the saisie function a reference to the space in memory where the 10th element of your int array would be, if it were 10 elements long; modify it so you pass in the array itself `saisie(B)`

Comment: Yes, the debug included in code blocks but he didn't find errors and warning ...

Comment: Actually, what is the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C are zero-indexed, so B[9] has elements in the 0..8 range. This is not valid:

```
saisie_B_M(&B[9]);
```

if you want to pass the pointer to the last element yo need to use:

```
saisie_B_M(&B[8]);
```

but it seems you need the complete array, so pass &B[0] (or simply B) to saisie_B_M function. Also your "for" loop should be changed to this:

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
/* ... */
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the spelling problems, you first statement is correct but your solution ignores what the OP is looking to do.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is when you call your function with

> saisie_B_M(&B[9]);

It should be

> saisie_B_M(B);

In the first case, you give an array but starting at the 9th offset `B[9]`. So your function will start iterating at 9th then 10th, 11th, 12th... the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on `@Miguel Prz`'s answer, if you wanted to start with the first element, then you need to pass a reference to the first element in the array: `saisie_B_M(&B[0])` or you could just use `saisie_B_M(B)`.